# I want to open a file (pdf, docx) in the browser with Nodejs

Tags: node.js

```
    $doc = Document::findOrFail($id);
    $path = Storage::disk('local')->getDriver()->getAdapter()->applyPathPrefix($doc->file);
    $type = $doc->mimetype;

   Log::addToLog('Document ID '.$id.' à été consulté');

    if ($type == 'application/pdf' || $type == 'image/jpeg' ||
        $type == 'image/png' || $type == 'image/jpg' || $type == 'image/gif')
    {
        return response()->file($path, ['Content-Type' => $type]);
    }
    elseif ($type == 'video/mp4' || $type == 'audio/mpeg' ||
        $type == 'audio/mp3' || $type == 'audio/x-m4a')
    {
        return view('documents.play',compact('doc'));
    }
    else {
        return response()->file($path, ['Content-Type' => $type]);
    }


}
```

Comment: What problem are you specifically having at the moment with this code?

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple if you can use Express framework of Node Js.

Express framework provides a sendFile() method available on the response object which can be used to send static files to the client.

Try the following code:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/static/test.pdf");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Puppeteer module....It helps you to achieve that

```
const Puppeteer = require('puppeteer'),
Handlebars = require('handlebars'),
_ = require('lodash'),
ReadFile = Util.promisify(Fs.readFile);

async createPDF(orderData){
        try{
            let me = this;

        let html = await me._bindTemplate(orderData);
        let browser = await Puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
        let page = await browser.newPage()

        await page.setContent(html);
        let d = new Date().getTime();
        let filename = `invoice-${orderData.order_id}-${d.toString().substr(-1,2)}.pdf`;
        let pdf = await page.pdf({ format: 'A4',path:`./lib/pdf/${filename}`});
        return filename;

        }catch(e){

            console.log(e)
            return e;
        }


    }

   async _bindTemplate(orderData){
       try{
        let me = this;

        const content = await ReadFile(Path.join(__dirname, './../../templates/invoiceTemplates.html'), 'utf8');
        const templateContent = Handlebars.compile(content);
        let data = loadRequiredTemplateDataforInvoicePDF(orderData);
        return templateContent(data);
       }catch(e){
           return e;
       }

    }

loadRequiredTemplateDataforInvoicePDF(order){
        let payload  = {};
        payload.id = order.order_id;
        payload.user = order.user;

        return payload;

    }
```

The above snippet will create pdf and returns you the name of file....You can call download function of response object to let the user gets their pdf file